# neo4j duration differences between "between" and "inSeconds"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am computing the differences between datetime1 and datetime2 in minutes. First created a test node

```
MERGE (x:Test {id: 1})
SET
x.date = date(),
x.datetime = datetime(),
x.timestamp = timestamp(),
x.date1 = date('2022-04-08'),
x.date2 = date('2022-09-20'),
x.datetime1 = datetime('2022-02-02T15:25:33'),
x.datetime2 = datetime('2022-02-02T22:06:12')
RETURN x
```

I know the correct query is:

```
match (x:Test)
return duration.between(x.datetime1, x.datetime2).minutes
```

But hy the following will return different result compare to the above?

```
match (x:Test)
return duration.inSeconds(x.date1, x.date2).seconds/60
```

My understanding is the first query produces the time differences in minutes and the second query produces the time differences in minutes because I divided the seconds results by 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in your queries are different:

```
match (x:Test)
return duration.inSeconds(x.date1, x.date2).seconds/60 <--- date1 and date2 here

match (x:Test)
return duration.between(x.datetime1, x.datetime2).minutes <--- datetime1 and datetime2 here
```

Try this, it will give the same output:

```
match (x:Test)
return duration.inSeconds(x.datetime1, x.datetime2).seconds/60 <--- date1 and date2 here
```